# PHPunit and netbeans debugging not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, xdebug

I have am trying to debug some PHPunit tests in netbeans, but it doesn't stop at my break-points.

I can, however, debug the site in the browser and it stops at my breakpoints.

I have modified file->project properties->run configuration->advanced to "do not open web browser".

I use the following script to initiate phpunit :

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=netbeans-xdebug";
phpunit $@
```

What could be the problem?

ps. I have had it working in the past, but it stopped working and I had to reinstall xdebug. I am using ubuntu 11.10

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your port is not set to listen on xdebug's default listener port 9000.

Here's some instructions on mac for netbeans but it should do the trick even if you're running windows.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-mac-os.html